# CQRS Separate View per different Clients? (Web, Desktop, Mobile)

Tags: domain-driven-design, soa, cqrs, event-sourcing, datacontract

We are building inventory system. We do CQRS and EventSourcing. WE have separate ReadModels (views) like OnHandSTockView, InTransitSTockView and so on, where each view has its state in db (1 view = 1 sql table, denormalized). When designing Service Contracts, how reusable should we design them? If Client A (WEb platform, React) needs inTransitView, and MobileClient needs inTransitView, with minor differences maybe in number of columns, should we keep 1 Table in Db and create 1 Service Contract(reusable for both clients) or create 2 tables per specific view per client with 2 service contracts? Or should it be 1 table in sql and 2 rest Endpoints for different clients?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to generalize, and what are you trying to optimize?

I would start with what you mentioned as first option: ***1 Table in Db and create 1 Service Contract (reusable for both clients)***, because that makes you reusing as much as possible, and moving responsibility to different clients, to use only the data they need.

If you start noticing that using ***2 endpoints and single denormalized table*** - one with simplified data, and one with extended data, saves you a lot of resources, then that would be logical next step. It's more contracts to maintain, so it's a maintenance cost for you, but it makes sense if it's planned optimization.

***2 tables per specific view per client with 2 service contracts*** - this and any other solution would probably be the result of you solving other specific problem with previous solutions. It makes sense for having same data, but used for different purposes, and optimized in different way. For example, same looking data, but one being used by search engine, and second being used as document database / relational database. That kind of projections might also be done in different ways than just projecting events as they are (i.e. connecting it with data from other projections in some way).

Comment: "1 Table in Db and create 1 Service Contract (reusable for both clients)" - Now I'm thinking maybe instead of having 1 table in db, better to have more (3-5) and then compose the result in my query handler, that would give me a real components reuse, cause I would be able to satisfy a lot more different usecases from different clients? Then what is cqrs read model for? Maybe I should treat it as a cache of data only, not as real resource component?

Comment: In my experience, read models in Event Sourcing solutions are most useful as some kind of cache. They don't need to represent Command Model that is created only based on events, they can have more data, even outside of given aggregate. I'm not able to tell what is best for your architecture, because this is more detailed question. You might get away of composing views based on many sql tables, if its performance will suffice.